# How to run wordpress along with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, express, seo

I am trying to run Wordpress blog along with the node + express project. I've tried all possible solutions from the google to run the wordpress blog in node js. (Trying since last 2 days).

Note : Our website is hosted on heroku server.

Reason why I met with this situation:

1. Our site is completely built on html, javascript and css with Wordpress blog (https://oursite.com/blog).
2. We are calling api using Ajax to fetch the data, which includes meta content too, and adding it on the html page using jQuery.
3. The API is crated on Strapi Framework which is hosted on another domain on heroku.
4. Our SEO expert told us that this will not work, because the website will not get crawled if the meta data will not shown in the page source.
5. So I googled and came-up with the node + express + ejs solution.
6. But now I'm not able to include wordress blog in my node project.

Comment: What you're looking for is a "headless CMS". There is tutorial on internet to help you find a solution in this way

Comment: @Pof - I've already searched for it and gave the solution to our seniors but they are not impressed with the solution and told to stick with the wordpress only.